# Use a network synchronized folder as Jupyter notebook directory on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, directory, jupyter-notebook

I am running Jupyter Notebook on a windows x64 machine. My documents folder is synchronized on a corporate network (green circle icon thing) and it looks like the path is \(network path stuff)...\myname\My Documents. I tried setting this (with backslashes replaced by forward slashes) as the value of c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir in my jupyter_notebook_config.py, but when I do that jupyter-notebook tells me "No such notebook dir:" and closes.

Is there any way to get Jupyter Notebook to use this synchronized path as the notebook directory? Apologize for the lack of clarity on what sort of synchronization applies to my windows folder.

Comment: is there any reason you cannot just use Powershell or the command prompt to `cd "\\NETWORKPATH\more\directory\myname\My Documents"` and then run jupyter?

Comment: thanks! That works, I had not considered that. I will post this as the answer in a bit.

Comment: actually, I realized that the problem was caused by my earlier failure to replace backslashes at the beginning of the network drive label. Oops!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to LinkBerest for helping me arrive at the following answer:

1. Replace ALL backslashes with slashes including the leading double backslashes (if any).
2. If specifying the default directory in the config file does not work, can remove the corresponding item from the config file and just navigate to the synced folder in got-bash before starting jupyter-notebook.

Whether specifying in the config file or navigating to the directory before starting, if I use the "replace all backslashes with slashes" then it works.

Comment: You should edit this to include the actual answer (basically summarize my comment including the psuedo-path)

Comment: In the end, I didn't need to navigate to that path and changing the config file worked. I will edit the answer to say that they both work, if that makes sense to you.

Comment: The idea is to edit the answer to be an answer for future readers who have the same problem (I've looked there aren't many windows shared directory questions) so anything which accomplishes that is helpful :)